# Path with least maximum edge weight

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, shortest-path

Let's say we have a directed non-negative-weighted graph.

We have to find the **least cost path** between (u, v).
The cost of a path is defined as the maximum cost of the **second** most expensive **edge** that the path contains.

Here's an example.

Graph with 4 nodes and 4 edges:

- from 1 to 2 at cost 3
- from 1 to 3 at cost 7
- from 2 to 3 at cost 5
- from 3 to 4 at cost 2

The optimal path between 1 and 4 should be 1 - 3 - 4 with total cost 2 (costs are 2 and 7, the second highest one is 2).

Dijkstra standard SSSP (reconstructing the path and finding the second highest edge) obviously doesn't work.
I've thought at MST (which should be OK) but it's not guaranteed to cover the best path (u,v).

Comment: There is no attempt at a solution here so you're not likely to get a response... Try solving it yourself, then if you have a problem come back and ask for help. Not to say you need code but at least some idea of how to approach the problem would be good

Comment: What happens if the edge weights in a path are 5,5,4? is the cost 4 or 5? Also, what if there's only one edge in the path?

Comment: Sorry about not having reported attempts. I've added some info. @genisage The costs would be respectively 5 and 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can binary search over the answer(sort the edges by their weight before it).
For a fixed answer c, let's call edges with weight > c heavy and other edges light.
So all you need to check is if there is path with at most 1 heavy edge. You can do it by assigning 0 cost to light edges and 1 to heavy ones and running 0-1 bfs. If the distance is <= 1, then it possible to obtain a path with a cost at most c.
The time complexity is O(E log E).

Comment: It doesn't work on a graph as the following:
1 -> 2 at cost 8 
2 -> 3 at cost 1 
3 -> 4 at cost 2 
4 -> 5 at cost 7 
3 -> 5 at cost 9.
Your idea would lead to 2 as answer, but the right output is 7.

Comment: @lucach You are right. I have edited my answer. It looks like it is correct now.

Answer (score 4):

We can get O(E + V log V), which is o(E log E) for sufficiently dense graphs. Using Dijkstra with a Fibonacci heap, compute two max-weight (as opposed to second max-weight) shortest path trees, one directed leafward from the root u, one directed rootward to the root v. For each edge s->t, consider the path consisting of the max-weight shortest path from u to s, the edge s->t, and the max-weight shortest path from t to v, whose second max-weight is bounded by taking the maximum of the u->s and t->v segments.

Comment: By Dijkstra I guess you mean Prim?

Comment: @tmyklebu I s'pose, but the idea of Prim operating on a directed graph seems more jarring than Dijkstra with a different relaxation formula.

Comment: I guess.  I don't really see a difference between the two other than that, though.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I consider your answer a more adequate approach since it doesn't involve bserach, however I can't figure out the proper relax formula to get a max-weight SP (also the meaning of _max-weight SP tree_ isn't 100% clear to me).

Comment: @lucach In a sentence, Dijkstra's algorithm works by storing vertices in a priority queue, where the key of a vertex is the cost of the cheapest known path to it. All we have to do when computing the new cost of a node is to replace length(path) + length(edge) by max(length(path), length(edge)), as in Prim's algorithm. (Saying Prim bothers me because there are faster MST algorithms, but they don't work in directed graphs.)

Answer (score 3):

Consider binary search for the optimum cost. Sort weights of all edges, and search for the least value `X` satisfying the condition:

```
There is a u -> v path which has at most one edge with weight greater than X.
```

How to check the condition? For a given `X`:

1. Run DFS from `u` and find set `U` of vertices reachable from `u` using edges of weight at most `X`. If `v` is in `U`, condition is satisfied.
2. Otherwise find according set `V` with DFS from `v`.
3. The condition is satisfied if and only if there exist an edge with one vertex in `U` and other in `V`.

Time complexity: `O(E log E)`.